# Why do the insertOne method from mongodb node.js driver mutates the object to be inserted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am learning mongodb with node, and I was playing with the following code

```js
var assert = require('assert')
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo'
var client = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var doc = {
  firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}
console.log(doc)  //logs as expected
client.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  assert.equal(err, null)
  var docs = db.collection('docs')
  docs.insertOne(doc, (err, result) => {
    assert.equal(err, null)
    console.log(doc)  //logs with an extra property i.e. _id
    db.close()
  })
})
```

I was surprised to see that `doc` is mutated by mongo, look at inspect the output of both of the `console.log` statements. Why is the `doc` object mutated.

Comment: Found the same behavior in the PyMongo driver, so likely it is part of the driver spec. I agree that it is very surprising that the original object is mutated. Questionable design choice, in my opinion.

Comment: I just spent like an hour debugging this because it exhibited some REALLY weird behaviour in a polyglot environment. I finally isolated it to the object I passed into MongoDB.insertOne(). It was secretly mutating and going into subsequent Neo4j query which was blowing up due the `_id: 59adf8f8346d4e1cb01108b7` getting illegally tacked on.

Comment: Everything was working fine until I added MongoDB and then it detonated elsewhere in the code because I literally just added `const addToMongo = await articles.insertOne(newArticle)` and all hell broke loose. It was an immutable nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo adds an automatically generated _id to every document that doesn't define one itself. This is a special object type called an ObjectId and is used as a primary key. You can see the details of the format [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

You can get around the auto-generated _id by adding your own to each object but you'll need to be able to guarantee that they're unique as if you try to store two objects with the same _id you'll get a duplicate key error.